# How to improve gif quality in PyQt6?

Tags: pyqt6

I'm coding in PyQt6 and I'd like to add a loading gif to my application. I've got a good quality 256px gif. However, after adding it to app (I used QLabel and QMovie, and added QMovie to QLabel - and I also changed size of the image to 40px using setScaledSize), the quality is much worse. Without scaling the image quality seems to be a bit better, but honestly I don't want to have 256px gif :D
I tried adding 64px and 40px gifs - but the quality was horrible as well.

My code:

```py
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt6.QtCore import QSize

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        loading = QLabel()
        gif = QMovie("loading.gif")
        gif.setFormat(b"gif")
        gif.setScaledSize(QSize(40,40))
        loading.setMovie(gif)
        gif.start()
        layout.addWidget(loading)


        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

app = QApplication([])

window = MainWindow()

window.show()

app.exec()
```

My gif is from here:
https://icons8.com/preloaders/en/circular
and it's called Position.gif
[image: Gif in app]

That's what it looks like in my app.

Any ideas on how to improve it would be great!

Comment: I get some light aliasing (probably caused by the high contrast and the "unrelated" scale), but it doesn't seem *that* bad. Can you provide a screenshot of what you see? Are you using a High DPI screen? Also, please write a comment or a note when updating the question, we cannot always follow all posts, and we might miss the changes.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment. I've never had such issues before, so I'd say it's rather not my screen's fault.